# Play video in html video tag that is stored in the GAE blobstore python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, html5-video, blobstore

I have a simple video sharing website that can upload videos and store them in the datastore as a blobReferenceProperty(). Now I am querying the datastore for that video and trying to imbed/play it in a html 5 video tag. It seems that I now need to find the path to the video that is stored in the blobstore because html 5 video tag wants a path.

The problem is that the video when queried from the blobstore comes back as a blob_key. Does anyone know how to get the path of a blob_key so it can be played by the html 5 video tag.

```
class Videos(db.Model):
    videoID = db.IntegerProperty()
    content = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

---

```
vids = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE videoID = :1", v_id)
    for v in vids:
      vid_key = v.content
```

Now I want the path of vid key so i can put it where the ???? are

```
<video controls>
    <source src="????" type="video/mp4">
   <p>Your browser does not support the HTML5 video element.</p>
 </video>
```

Any ideas?

[edit]

I already have a download handler that looks like this

```
class Play(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, vid_id): 
        vid_key = None
        vids = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE videoID = :1", int(vid_id)) 
        for v in vids: 
            vid_key = v.content 
        if (vid_key == None): 
            self.error(404) 
        else: 
            self.send_blob(vid_key)
```

Right now my code serves the video full screen, I want to switch this to play the video imbedded in my website within an html 5 video tag. That has comments and ratings on the same page

Comment: It seems like you are using the handler as a response page - so when you try to get the url its going directly to the video url.  Try using a separate response page that calls the handler. If you have problems I can try to provide a code example

Comment: Yes I am using it as a response page. But I think that is what I want to do. Instead of serving the video by the code: self.send_blob(vid_key) - I want to set some variable, lets call it 'path' as the path of the blob_key. How would separating it to another response page help me?

Comment: I figured it out. When serving the video, it gave me the url for the video. I took that url and subbed in each individual video ID to dynamically give the HTML video tag a source. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to get it working.

Comment: @ScottB Could you please help me fix a [very similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24103934/1443563)

Comment: @JayS. Could you please help me fix a [very similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24103934/1443563)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a BlobstoreDownloadHandler to serve the blob. Easiest would be to have the blob resource identified in the url by the string representation of the blobkey i.e. mypath.com/blobs/blobkey Then you could easily reference that url using the reference property in your Videos model.

To create the BlobstoreDownloadHandler, you can read the documentation: [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob) and [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers#BlobstoreDownloadHandler).