# How to play(stream instead of download) video file which was stored in GCS using Blobstore API

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

How to play(stream instead of download) a video file stored in GCS? The file was stored using Blobstore API in GAE Python? 
Presently, the video gets downloaded when I use the url, returned by send_blob, in the frontend.

**I serve the video using:**

```
video_url = "/v?video_id="+video_blobkey 

:: 

class GCSFileServe(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get (self): 
        blob_key = self.request.get('video_id') 
        self.send_blob(blob_key) 

:: 

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler), 
    ('/v', GCSFileServe), 
], debug=True)
```

**I upload the video and store the blobkey:**

```
filename = bucket + "/user_video_"+str (user_index) + "_" + str (i) 
gcs_file = gcs.open (filename, 'w', content_type = 'video/avi') 
gcs_file.write (video) 
gcs_file.close () 
blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename 
video_blobkey = blobstore.create_gs_key (blobstore_filename)
```

On frontend, i pass the video URL to [TINY Box 2 jquery modal plugin](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/). This works perfectly if I provide youtube url instead of the video uploaded to GCS.

I saw [Streaming Transfers topic in GCS docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#streaming) but could understand how to use that in this context(if that is the solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out myself. 
Actually, there was no problem with the way I am serving the video. The problem was with the [Galleria jquery plugin](http://galleria.io/) which I was using. It can play videos from youtube, and a few more websites, but not if you specify a different URL (like of a self hosted video file).

**Solution**
I switched over to [Videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) for playing videos on my website.